# stuck with status check of amazon ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am using Python to launch an `ec2 instance`, after I get `"running"` state of my instance, I am trying to `SCP` a shell script and run it via ssh.

I am getting the following error

> "ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused"

When I check in the console, the Status check is `"Initializing"`, once It changes `"2/2 checks passed"`, I am able to `ssh` or run any script.

Is there any way I can get the "status check" via `python boto API`?

I am using Python 2.7.5+,
boto 2.19.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this problem? I am struggling with something very similar.

Answer (score 4):

Simple way is to check the port 22 of the newly created instance is reachable or not by using `socket` module

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
     s.connect(('hostname', 22))
     print "Port 22 reachable"
except socket.error as e:
     print "Error on connect: %s" % e
s.close()
```

When you will able to reach the port 22 then you can invoke ssh to it.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy way

```
import boto.ec2

for region in boto.ec2.regions():
        connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region.name, 
            aws_access_key_id = '<aws access key>', aws_secret_access_key = '<aws secret key>')
        existing_instances = connection.get_all_instance_status()
        print 'Listing instances from region ' + region.name
        for instance in existing_instances:
            print instance.system_status.status + '/' + instance.instance_status.status
```

Comment: Hi Felipe - Are you familiar with the error the user is having above? I am experiencing it currently and was wondering if you have any recommendations. I have used what you recommend but I still get connection errors.

Comment: You should look into Boto Waiters, for this specific case, the InstanceStatusOk waiter. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk

Comment: Thanks Felipe! Will look.