# Check if remote linux server is running or not?

Tags: php, linux, shell, amazon-ec2, ping

We have 10 EC2 instances (Linux CentOs).
At a given point of time, some instances may run and some may be shutdown
(we do not run http service on any server)

Is there any possibility from script(linux or php or any) to check how many servers(out of 10) are up and running now from another linux server which we continuously run ?

please suggest

Comment: check this may be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780572/stuck-with-status-check-of-amazon-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

For each instance run

```
ping -c3 <your machine address>
ret = $?                              // Get last error or success
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then               // If success meas instance is running
    //Increment counter or do whatever you want
fi
```

I have not tested it though